# htaccess redirect query to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect from `http://olddomain.com/pageDisplay.asp?key=5` to `http://newdomain.com/about/`

I have tried many variations of the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^oldomain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^key=5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pageDisplay\.asp$ http://newdomain.com/about/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

I swear these things are like witchcraft to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^pageDisplay.asp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=5$
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/about/? [R=301]
```